# How do just get a list of all links by using a recursive wget?

Tags: wget

I would like to get a list of all of all of the links on a given webpage (recursively).  I can't seem to find out how to do it without just going a wget -r .  I don't want to save all of the junk, just the links.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2833867/370940

Answer (score 0):

I use this commands to get only YouTube videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX)

```
wget --spider --force-html -r -l2 "https://www.youtube.com"  2>&1 | grep --color  'watch?v='
```

You can use this and change grep options like this:
For my example ,if yuou want to skip YouTube videos use 'grep -v ':

```
wget --spider --force-html -r -l2 "https://www.youtube.com"  2>&1 | grep -v 'watch?v='
```